# Passing data and submit functions between controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Basically when the user submits a calculation is done to the data and it is stored in a variable. I had it working when it was all in one controller, but now I need to split it between pages. I want to do this with a service. As you will see, I'm really confused and I know that I'm basically completely doing this wrong. I am not sure where I am going astray or maybe what I should look into to get a better handle on my misunderstanding - any help is really appreciated. Even just a basic pointer would be nice:

```
.factory('meals', function() {
    var data = {
        basePrice: 0,
        taxRate: 0,
        tipPercentage: 0,
        mealCount: 0,
        tipTotal: 0,
        averageTip: 0,
        subtotal: 0,
        tip: 0,
        tipTotal: 0,
        total:0
    }
    function set(data) {
        savedData = data;
    }
    function get(){
        return savedData;
    }
    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
})
.controller('HomeCtrl', [function(meals) {
}])
.controller('MealCtrl', [function(meals) {
    var ws = this;
    meals.set();
    ws.data = meals.get();

    ws.submit = function(){
        ws.tax_rate= ws.taxRate/100;
        ws.tip_rate= ws.tipPercentage/100;
        ws.subtotal= ws.basePrice*ws.tax_rate;
        ws.tip = ws.basePrice*ws.tip_rate;
        ws.total = ws.basePrice+ws.subtotal+ws.tip;
        ws.mealCount+=1;
        ws.tipTotal+=ws.tip;
        ws.averageTip=(ws.tipTotal+ws.tip)/ws.mealCount;
        items.tipTotal=ws.tipTotal;
        items.mealCount=ws.mealCount;
        items.averageTip=ws.averageTip;
    };

    ws.cancel = function(){
        ws.basePrice='';
        ws.taxRate='';
        ws.tipPercentage='';
    };

    ws.double = function(value){return value*2;};
}]).controller('EarningsCtrl', [function(meals) {
```

and the HTML:

```
<h2>Enter the Meal Details</h2>

<form name="Calculator" ng-submit="ws.submit()">
    <p>Base Meal Price:</p>
    <input type="number" ng-model="ws.basePrice" required> <br>
    <p>Tax Rate: %</p>
    <input type="number" ng-model="ws.taxRate" required> <br>
    <p>Tip Percentage: %</p>
    <input type="number" ng-model="ws.tipPercentage" required> <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<button ng-click="ws.cancel()">Cancel</button>

<h2>Customer Charges</h2>
    <p>Base Price {{ws.data.basePrice | currency}}</p>
    <p>Subtotal {{ws.subtotal | currency}}</p>
    <p>Tip {{ws.tip | currency}}</p>
    <p>Total {{ws.total | currency}}</p>
```

Comment: One problem is `meals.set();` doesn't have any parameters but in service it expects `data` argument. That `data` is not the same scope as the object `data` above it. So next line `ws.data = meals.get();
` will be undefined

Comment: I just can't figure out how to get the base price between things. maybe a more basic question... how would I get the data.basePrice object into one of the controllers? I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: change the `get()` to return the object `function get(){
        return data;
    }`

Comment: `saveData` is not defined,  `meals.set()`should have a parameter `var data`is never used